# Rails ActiveRecord method to list attributes including associated virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a method to list all of an active record class's attributes from database column names as well as attributes from associations?

`Foo.attribute_names` doesn't include virtual attributes generated from associations

`Foo.new.methods` *does include* these (as well as a huge list of unrelated methods), but I'd like a more pared down list of methods that are only related to ActiveRecord attributes if possible.

Is there a *correct* way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my book, the correct way is to use `attr_accessible` to define accessible attributes. Then on your model you can simply call `Foo.accessible_attributes` and get a nice list.

However, associations are trickier, but you can do something like:

```
Foo.accessible_attributes.to_a + Foo.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name)
```

If you aren't using `attr_accessible` you'd have to hack it together with

```
Bundle.new.attributes.keys - Bundle.protected_attributes.to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of exact Rails method for your case, but you can get around by doing something like..

`Model.attribute_names +  Model.reflect_on_all_associations.map {|a| a.name.to_s }`

The second part will give you associated model methods as strings in an array.